# Boot Troubles with Intel RSTe: Ubuntu Server Installation on Non-RAID Drive

Tags: boot, rst

I'm seeking assistance with a unique setup involving the following components:

- CPU: Intel Xeon E-2378
- SSD: Intel D3-S4620
- Motherboard: Supermicro x12stl-if
- BIOS Firmware Version: 1.0a
- BIOS settings: Default

I've recently installed **Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS** on my Intel D3-S4620 SSD, and initially, the installation went smoothly, and I was able to boot without any issues. However, trouble arose when I attempted to change the SATA mode to Intel RSTe (Intel Rapid Storage Technology enterprise). After making this switch, I found that I couldn't boot into Ubuntu. It's worth noting that switching the SATA mode back to AHCI allowed me to boot successfully again.

I've consulted the [official Ubuntu documentation on RSTe](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/), but unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution to my problem. Additionally, I attempted to reinstall Ubuntu with Intel RSTe enabled, but encountered the same booting problem.

My primary question is whether it's possible to boot from a non-RAID drive with Intel RSTe enabled, and if so, what steps I might be missing or if there are any known issues with this configuration.

Your insights and assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance.